# iPhone Facebook app: Finding out where the error is?

Tags: iphone, ios, syntax, upload, facebook-graph-api

So I just added Facebook to a previous app that was working. And I basically just included the code for a button press to upload/post the picture selected to Facebook -- nothing happened.

Are there any good resources for learning the syntax for iOS Facebook apps? Because I'm lost. Also, could you tell me why this seemingly simple code doesn't work? Because I pretty much copied it from the demo app example.

```
- (IBAction) sendPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    for(UIViewController *controller in self.tabBarController.viewControllers)
    {
        if([controller isKindOfClass:[FirstViewController class]])
        {
            FirstViewController *firstViewController = (FirstViewController *)controller;
            [firstViewController realLabel];
        }
    }
    Facebook *facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"198223696897308"];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   image, @"picture",
                                   nil];

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                          andParams:params
                      andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                        andDelegate:self];

    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;//switch over to the first view to see if it worked
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'd do is verify that the method is actually being called by setting a breakpoint or outputting a log statement.

The second thing I'd do is look at the API documentation to see if any of the methods I'm calling provide errors in any way.  They almost certainly do, so check what they say.

The third thing I'd do is set the device to use a proxy (e.g. [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)) to see if the requests are actually being sent out over the wire.

Comment: thanks Jim! :-) ... and for clarification, what API documentation are you referring to? Because I haven't found Facebook's documentation to be all that helpful. Or maybe I'm not looking in the right place. Could you send a link?

Comment: I just looked at the demo app, and that includes an error handler.  Why didn't you use that to debug?

Comment: It's mainly because I don't understand what's going on. I do see the error handler towards the bottom though and I'll try implementing it in the future. I'm confused about the Graph API and how it relates to Objective-C still. Most of Facebook's examples don't really tell me anything about how to make the call using objective-c (e.g., https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/). I'm missing a large chunk of what I'm suppose to be doing. Can you recommend any starting points -- ideally, not from Facebook.com since I haven't had too much luck with them. Thanks again Jim

Comment: The error handler isn't a "nice to have" feature, it will tell you what is going wrong, so that should be your very next step.  The GitHub project is where you should start for handling the iOS side of things, the documentation on facebook.com is where you should start when you need to figure out what you want to send to Facebook.

Comment: I wouldn't really know what to do with an error but got it - will implement that as my next step. Thanks again Jim.

Comment: Hi @Jim could you help me with another facebook related question (i.e., tagging a photo)? Because you seem to be very knowledgeable about the facebook sdk and objective-c. The other question is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566036/iphone-facebook-app-http-post-for-tagging-not-working)